Can't remove keys from ssh known_hosts: invalid line
After openssh-server upgrade it is impossible to remove old keys from known_hosts file because ssh-keygen gives:
$ ssh-keygen -R oldserver
/home/grin/.ssh/known_hosts:1: invalid line
/home/grin/.ssh/known_hosts:12: invalid line
/home/grin/.ssh/known_hosts:123: invalid line
Not replacing existing known_hosts file because of errors

Do I have to remove these lines individually?

If all the errors have one root reason
One possible reason is that known_hosts contain keys with obsolete, and now unsupported methods.
In my case it was ssh-dss method removed from ssh, and ssh-keygen failed to hande that nicely.
In this case the problem can be solved by removing all old unsupported keys:
$ grep -Fv 'ssh-dss' ~/.ssh/known_hosts > /tmp/known_hosts1
$ mv -v ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts.bak
$ mv -v /tmp/known_hosts1 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Removing illegal lines using the output
Here's a generic removal of illegal lines regardless of the reason (uses the fact tat the line numbers are between ":", using cut to get the number, then sed to remove that line in reverse nuberical order, since the file is getting shorter by every removal):
$ cp -av ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts.bak
$ ssh-keygen -R oldserver | cut -d: -f2 | sort -rg | \
   while read num; do sed -i ${num}d ~/.ssh/known_hosts; done

(I am sure there are nicer ways, and gladly welcome shell [sed/awk] gurus offer their better methods.)
If there are just a few lines of error
…then the lines can be simply removed by a text editor, jumping at the given position.

One can remove any specific line by using sed -i.bak 123d ~/.ssh/known_hosts (example was line 123).

It's a plain text file, so why not just edit it with vi or nano?

@BobGoddard because if you get a list of 850 invalid lines you would be unhappy (I used a loop, but yeah, maybe I should include that too). Also one may not remember how to jump at a line at a specific position.
